# Storyboard - ViewController to tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I have view controller which is the main interface contains options etc...

i want to transition from 1st view controller > tab controller

now once at tab controller i want to add more tabs as by default xcode only creates two.

q) how you add more tabs in storyboarding

I embeded the 1st view controller in tab controller but it crashed xcode

q) how to avoid crashing and making the flow seems better

any suggestions, ideas will be welcomed: coming from android activities and intents i'm not sure what is best solution here so welcome all input.

UPDATE: i guess what i was trying to ask and didnt made it clear is

i have view controller i want this to load first and upon clicking one of the three buttons go to tab controller which is where xcode crashes when i do Editor > embed within nav controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you could do worse than follow along a Storyboard tutorial. I found Ray Wenderlich's rather good. In fact I even purchased his book to get the whole thing.

See http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 27):

> How do you add more tabs in storyboarding?

Just add another view controller to the storyboard. Then, control-drag a connection from the tab controller to the new view controller, and choose "Relationship - viewControllers" from the popup menu that appears.

> How do you avoid crashing and improve the flow?

I've seen the storyboard editor crash Xcode every once in a while. If you have time, report a bug to Apple. Chances are that they already know about the problem, but another bug report never hurts, and it may increase the priority of the bug. Other than that, relaunch Xcode and continue what you were doing -- it usually works fine the second time around.

Improving the flow of the program from the user's point of view is a design problem; one approach is to try whatever you think will work best first, and then test thoroughly to identify the rough spots. Fix and repeat as necessary, and be sure to have other people try it too.

Comment: thx for that, do you know how to include viewcontorller to laod first and upon clicking some buttons on the main view controller we move to tab contoller, any examples or links?