# Navigating to a TabBarController from a ViewController in iOS 5 using storyboard

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I started developing my app with a TabBarController but I recently realized the use of authenticating the user before accessing the app.  So I created a login page before TabBarContoller(2 tabs and 2 views). But now I am not able to push the controller from ViewController to TabBarController.
What, I have tried so far is: (After the user taps the submit button on login page):

```
   UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"twoOptions"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Here, twoOptions is the identifier I have named in the Interface Builder for the TabBarController in StoryBoard

Please guide me

I went through the following link:
[ViewController to TabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763475/storyboard-viewcontroller-to-tab-bar-controller?rq=1) but still did not understand what needs to be done. I am unable to push the view

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Link for the example](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.in/2012/08/adding-uitabbarcontroller-in.html).

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController,secondViewController,thirdViewController, nil];
[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

I don't know know why are you using storyboard, but it can be easily done with the code also.

Comment: @Gilles at 26.5k reputation, you are probably seeing storyboards like those at intl space station looking at earth. ;) I wish I were like that too, but for the beginner as me, it seems a good tool :)