# How to change view controller to tab bar controller as root view controller

Tags: ios, ios9

I set the simple view controller as root view controller through navigation controller. Now I want to set the tab bar controller as root view controller.  I am using Objective-C with Xcode 7.

Comment: Please provide the code you working to make it more obvious what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with @Erik.  Also I think that question has answers already on stack overflow, so please search (google) or stackoverflow in various ways to find it. I found this with just a super quick search. I'm sure it's essentially a duplicate question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763475/storyboard-viewcontroller-to-tab-bar-controller

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're inside a view controller when you want to switch, you could use:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [self storyboard];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
self.view.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

Otherwise, you could call your app delegate and have it switch using its `window` property.